# How to get the sum from the JSON file use Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have code which read data from JSON file

```
    i = 0

while i < 10:
    with open('output/{}.json'.format(i), 'r') as jsonFile:
        jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
        jsonData = jsonObject["attributes"]
        jsonFile.close()

        for x in jsonData:
            keys = x.values()
            #print(keys)
            price = x["price"]
            print(price)
```

I have  output like this:
[image]

Question:
How can I return the sum of price?

PS My JSON file

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Background",
            "value": "brown",
            "price": 35
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Rock",
            "value": "red",
            "price": 100
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Apron",
            "value": "white",
            "price": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the dictionaries and sum the values with `sum()`

```
with open('output.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
    jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonData = jsonObject["attributes"]

print(sum(d['price'] for d in jsonData)) # 235
```

As a side note, when you use `with` you don't need to close the file explicitly, remove `jsonFile.close()`.